# How two take component of horizontally composed nat. trans.

Tags: category-theory

I know that for *vertical composition*, given two natural transformations $\varepsilon: G \to H, \eta: F \to G$:

$$(\varepsilon \eta)_X = \varepsilon_X \eta_X$$

But how would that equation look like for *horizontal composition*, given two natural transformations $\varepsilon: (J: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{E}) \to K, \eta: (F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}) \to G$:

$$(\varepsilon \eta)= \phantom{ } ?$$

Of course, I know:

$$
(\varepsilon J)_X = \varepsilon_{J(X)} \\
(F        \eta)_X = F(\eta_X)
$$

Comment: Since for every object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$ we have that $\varepsilon_{G(X)}\circ J(\eta_X) = K(\eta_X) \circ \varepsilon_{F(X)}$ by naturality of $\epsilon$, I would say that this is their horizontal composition, isn't it?

Comment: To distinghuish both compositions I should write $\varepsilon\bullet\eta$ for the vertical and $\epsilon\eta$ or
$\varepsilon\circ\eta$ for the horizontal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\varepsilon:J\stackrel{\bullet}{\to}K$ and $\eta: F\stackrel{\bullet}{\to}G$ and the functors $J,F$ are composable then $\varepsilon\eta:JF\stackrel{\bullet}{\to}KG$ with:$$(\varepsilon\eta)_x=\varepsilon_{Gx}\circ J\eta_x=K\eta_x\circ\varepsilon_{Fx}:JFx\to KGx$$

The following diagram commutes:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
JFx & \stackrel{\varepsilon_{Fx}}{\longrightarrow} & KFx\\
J\eta_{x}\downarrow &  & \downarrow K\eta_{x}\\
JGx & \stackrel{\varepsilon_{Gx}}{\longrightarrow} & KGx
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you, the graph really made it click